# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS: Keyboard and mouse do not work in BOTH sign-in screen as well as recovery for all kernel versions newer than 5.11.0-43-generic

Tags: kernel, keyboard, mouse, recovery-mode

**IMPORTANT: Also, the recovery for 5.11.0-43-generic (My only working kernel currently) has the same issue.** The keyboard does not function in recovery on any kernel I have installed. However, 5.11.0-43-generic is the only kernel I can use my keyboard and mouse on.

I was a Linux noob when I installed this machine and I have my /home/ directory on the same partition as my /boot/ directory... I could just reinstall but that's a hassle. I want a less nuclear-option solution to this problem in case it happens again in the future.

A lot of articles I'm finding on this issue involve laptops, or involve commands in recovery which I'm unable to access. Is there a solution I can do while logged in normally?

Comment: What sort of hardware are you using? A brand/model of the keyboard and mouse would be a good start, as well as knowing more about your computer. Re-installation is rarely necessary unless a destructive action has been performed. Ubuntu != Windows95 

Comment: I'm using a Corsair K95 keyboard, and a cheepo chinese mouse that was supposedly a PICTEK gaming mouse (lsusb lists it as "SINOWEALTH wired gaming mouse". )

I know linux isn't windows. Just a lot of guides I came across suggested a reinstall to fix the issue. Like sure, using a thermonuclear bomb to kill a cockroach will work but there are easier ways I'm sure.

I'm using KDE Plasma for my GUI, Intel i7-6700k CPU, NVIDIA Geforce RTX 2070 Super (latest drivers 470.86), latest BIOS for my motherboard, and a whole bunch of HDDs and SSDs with a USB hub for peripherals.

Comment: Also it's worth mentioning that it still doesn't work with a backup logitech keyboard. It's not taking any keyboard input from either keyboards.

Comment: Have you booted into a Live Session with the installation USB to rule out configuration file issues? 

Comment: I'll give that a shot. I think I have a recent version of Ubuntu on my USB's Ventoy partition. I'll report back.

Comment: Does this apply to 5.13 kernels, as the 5.11 kernel (from [Ubuntu 21.04](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2022-January/000276.html)) is now EOL; with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS systems already having upgraded to 5.13.

Comment: Keep in mind this isn't an answer but have you tried unplugging and plugging the mouse/keyboard back in while you're on the sign in screen and/or in recovery mode? I have a computer that does this sometimes when using a certain setup. It works on grub but the keyboard and mouse shut off and I have to unplug and plug them back in. This might be able to get recovery mode working.

Comment: guiverc yes the 5.13 kernels are having the exact same issue. I'm certain it's not the kernel but something else at this point. There's no way it's that many version of kernels.

Comment: mchid yeah I've tried unplugging and pluggin in the keyboard. I've also tried waiting at the sign in screen and the recover screen for a couple minutes to see if either device lights up. Maybe I'll try waiting longer in recover mode in case it's slowly indexing through USB addresses that are unresponsive or something.

Comment: Just came back from testing the live USB. The version I used was 5.11.0-27-generic IIRC. Keyboard and mouse worked without issue. The kernel version is out of date on the Ubuntu ISO and I'm not going to fart around trying to install updates to my USB or install to a disk. Now we know the K+M work with newer kernel versions. Definitely something wrong with my configuration.